# jsdom, automation, scraping, dynamic frames

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, frameset, jsdom

I am trying scrape, automate my activities at the following address.
https://www5.fdic.gov/idasp/main.asp
basically fill out the form, submit etc..

I've been successful at automating with greasemonkey and am considering rebuilding using node.

Question: will the jsdom browser emu environment allow me to access and manipulate the dynamic frames rendered at the above site.

if yes. Can you point me to examples I can play with?

Note: I am aware of Phantomjs and Selenium but am more interested in using jsdom for the solution.

my code thus far:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var jsdom   = require('jsdom');
var app     = express();
var port    = '8081';

require('jsdom').defaultDocumentFeatures = {
      FetchExternalResources   : true, 
      ProcessExternalResources : true,
      MutationEvents           : '2.0',
      QuerySelector            : true
}


app.get('/', function(req, res){
url = 'https://www5.fdic.gov/idasp/main.asp';   
jsdom.env(
            url,
            ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1273929/JS/functions/jquery-1.11.1.js"],
            function (err, window) {
                //var $ = window.$;
                var nodes = window.jQuery('frame[name=content]').context._childNodes
                console.log(nodes);
                res.send(window.location._document._URL + '\n');
            }
        );  


})

app.listen(port)
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: i would think tampermonkey would work a lot simpler, if not better.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a few examples on how to use jsdom with frames in the jsdom [tests](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/test/window/frame.js).

However, it is important to note that jsdom itself does not support navigation and therefore also can't submit your form. [Zombie.js](http://zombie.js.org/) uses jsdom internally and extends it with a few features - form submission being one of them I believe.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. Will explore the Zombie.js option you've suggested.